# <h2> class inheriting from general <h2>

Tags: css, inheritance

I know many inheritance questions have been asked, but each case is unique and I'm having trouble with this one.

I have some h2 elements that need to have unique styling to them but they keep inheriting properties from previously defined h2 elements.

I've tried giving them a unique class, I've tried defining css properties through JS and Jquery, nothing's working.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h2>Original H2</h2>
    <div class="child">
        <h2>New H2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent h2 {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}

.child h2 {
     font-weight:normal;
     color:green;
}
```

Even with giving the child's h2 tag a unique class I get nowhere.

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h2>Original H2</h2>
    <div class="child">
        <h2 class="newh2class">New H2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent h2 {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}

.child h2.newh2class {
     font-weight:normal;
     color:green;
}

<!--or-->

h2.newh2class {
     font-weight:normal;
     color:green;    
}
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Nothing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/SmUGm/

Comment: What are they inheriting?

Comment: They're inheriting font styles and colors. I'd post the specific code but it's work-related.

Comment: You could use the `>` in CSS so the style gets only applied to the direct descendant. Like for example `.parent > h2` will only be applied to your first `h2`

Comment: Purge your browser cache.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance. Please explain what the problem is: what exactly do you wish to achieved, and how does the actual rendering differ from the expected?

Comment: Thanks putvande! You just made my day :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use !important value to make it so.

```
h2.newh2class {
    font-weight:normal;
    color:green !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You css should look like this

```
.parent > h2 {
     font-weight:bold;
     color:red;
}

.child h2 {
      font-weight:normal;
      color:green;
}
```

check it here http://jsfiddle.net/yNFUd/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is CSS because of how your are referencing the element. Read about [stacking and precedence in CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/SmUGm/2/

```
.parent > h2 {
     font-weight:bold;
     color:red;
}

.parent .child h2 {
      color:blue;    
}

.child > h2 {
      font-weight:normal;
      color:green; 
}
```

Changing the order and how they are called will affect how they are inherited and calculated.